# Google Script drive uploader creating duplicate folders

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have used this: [Google Drive Uploader](https://script.google.com/d/1do8zVTH9-3ktxrxaUOP-pM2Hqz6ZmHcRt7chG9C8evn1hbDx6sweWPrR/edit?usp=sharing) to create a google script to upload multiple files to my designated folder in my Google Drive. This creates a subfolder in the designated folder with the name entered and then uploads the selected files into that folder. The upload process is working perfectly, but sometimes it creates multiple folders of the same name and causes the files to be distributed unevenly into these duplicate folders. Please help to resolve this bug. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the credits lines. Maybe you should contact the developper who wrote the code, who will be glad that someone let him know abour errors and bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; I didn't find any solution to ony create a file in a folder without creating it in root.
My counter solution is to create the file and delete the root's duplicate. This solution is dirty but it work.